# Why I can't see the metadata in Windows?

Tags: rendering, image

I wrote some metadata to my output image (png) and can't see it in windows.

[image]

[image]

Also, I wrote antoher image (exr) with nodes in Compositor and there are even less metadata written. Should I assume that the metadata is only written to the output file and not the File Output node from compositor?

[image]

Comment: There are other free programs for Windows which can show you the metadata.  Please search for XNView.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I did it and now I can see the metadata. So that means it's windows that can't read the metadata written by Blender, not Blender writting it wrong.
It's a pity, I wish I could read it with the native Windows tools.
Thanks again for the workaround

Comment: I have no idea whether Microsoft Corporation will devote time and resources to show various types of satellite data in the Windows Explorer or other programs.  I think there are various type of meta data, EXIF et cetera. One can search some metadata for images with Windows Explorer, at present. All vague memories.  Although I rarely use XNView, I have used it to show me which Blender file created the image.  I do think your question is loosely related to Blender as I just gave an example. Blender creates metadata.  Immoderators seem to thrive on closing  questions as some form of indulgence.